# unable to create id_resolver keyring for nfs id mapping

Tags: centos, nfs

Trying to use id mapping on my nfs server, clientside everything is working fine but on my server when I run `sudo nfsidmap` with any options all I get is `nfsidmap: '.id_resolver' keyring was not found.`

`sudo nfsidmap -c` does nothing, and I can't find any entries in journalctl that mention the creation of the id_resolver keyring, so I have to assume that it's not being created for some reason. nfs-idmapd.service, nfs-server.service, nfs-mountd.service, rpc-statd.service, and rpcbind.service are all active with no errors. Here's what's in /etc/request-key.d/id_resolver.conf:

```
#
# nfsidmap(5) - The NFS idmapper upcall program
# Summary: Used by NFSv4 to map user/group ids into 
#          user/group names and names into in ids
# Options:
# -v         Increases the verbosity of the output to syslog
# -t timeout Set the expiration timer, in seconds, on the key
#
create    id_resolver   *   *   /usr/sbin/nfsidmap %k %d
```

help.

centos 7 kernel 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
nfs-utils version 1.3.0 release 0.33.el7_3